# What causes "Bad Process ID"?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Three of about seven .exe's in a collection of Delphi apps are failing on just one customer's 64-bit Win7 machine.

The message is:

> Exception Exception in module ProgName.exe at 002f2baf
>   Bad Process ID

The address is the same in two apps, and 002bd3f in the third.

This is a standalone app, running  Paradox/BDE, which in spite of its age and our need to migrate, continues run our app on many, many machines in the field.

We don't do any threading.

Googling the message "Bad Process ID" has turned up nothing that looks relevant.

Any suggestions on what this message is about?

Comment: Use something like madExcept to get a diagnostic stack trace and discover which code is executing. It costs a little money but it is great value.

Comment: Also check the Windows Event Log, maybe it contains additional information

Comment: You can also get stack trace with JCL. You can check my simple log that can automatically catch unhandled and handled exceptions and logs the stack trace of the event. URL: http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplelog It is a simple tool and so not a replacement for heavy weight logging tools. But it does the job and its free and easy to use.

Comment: David: as usual, your suggestion got us to an answer. madExcept allowed us to trace the bug down to some ancient code in our system that was failing when enumerating processes. If you post as an answer, I'll flag it as such. Than you ... again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information provided it's pretty much impossible to say what is the cause of the problem. So what you need is a means to gather more concrete information. I recommend using a debugging tool such as madExcept or EurekaLog. These will produce stack traces at the point at which the error occurs and often that gives you enough information to work out the underlying root cause.